# How to create a new service area analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, service-area

I need to create and run a new service area analysis. I'll need to do an analysis of how far you are coming by car from one hospital in 30 min, 60 min and 90 min. Is there anyone who can help me with a model of this in ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the step-by-step tutorial on how to calculate [Service Areas.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_5_Calculating_service_areas_and_creating_an_OD_cost_matrix/004700000060000000/) 
If you want to run the same analysis but several times providing multiple values for the operation, you might consider using the [Make Service Area Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Service_Area_Layer/00480000000p000000/) and the [Solve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Solve/00480000000r000000/) GP tools. There is a separate [tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_6_Creating_a_model_for_route_analysis/004700000061000000/) on this, too. If you need to build anything more advanced, consider using the [Iterators](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000001n000000) in ModelBuilder or [arcpy.na](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ServiceAreaSolverProperties/01mr00000003000000/) module for that.